# Maximal image width in Wygwam field

Tags: wygwam, image, assets

Is there any possibility to set a maximal width (or height) for the image selection modal window in wygwam?

Comment: Does anything in this thread possibly help? http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/Define-max-image-width-when-added-editor-3.4.2  There isn't a Wygwam approach to this; so looking to CKEditor is the best way to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about setting it to enforce prior to upload, but it can be enforced after the fact in-template using [CE Image's bulk tag pair](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/basics) wrapped around your Wygwam custom field.